# Unix time to regular date and time format using pyspark

Tags: datetime, pyspark, time, unix-timestamp

I have unix time data from some logs, I want to transform then into regular dates and time

for example I have *1683825723389* and I get *+553280424* or *+55328-04-24 15:36:29*

I tried:

```
.withColumn("date", F.from_unixtime(F.col("unix_time_column"), "yyyyMMdd")

.withColumn("time", F.from_unixtime("unix_time_column"))

.withColumn("date", F.expr("from_unixtime(unix_time_column)")

.withColumn("date", F.col("unix_time_column").cast('date'))
```

But nothing seems to work

Thanks.

Comment: `1683825723389` is in milliseconds and `from_unixtime` converts number in seconds to datetime.  Try `F.from_unixtime(F.col("unix_time_column") / 1000, "yyyyMMdd")`

Comment: Hi Emma, yes that was all, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Emma in the comments the time is in milliseconds, is just to divide by 1000

Answer (score 0):

Using **`SQL API:`**

`timestamp_millis() + date_format()` functions starting from **`Spark-3.1.0+`**

**`Example:`**

```
select date_format((timestamp_millis(1683825723389)),'yyyyMMdd') as dt
#output
#20230511
```

---

```
select (timestamp_millis(1683825723389)) as ts_millis
#2023-05-11T17:22:03.389+0000
```

---

Another approach is by using **timestamp_seconds** function for dataframe API.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1683825723389,)],['ts_millis'])
df.show(10,False)
df.withColumn("dt_frmt", date_format(timestamp_seconds(col("ts_millis")/1000),"yyyyMMdd")).show(10,False)

#+-------------+
#|ts_millis    |
#+-------------+
#|1683825723389|
#+-------------+

#+-------------+--------+
#|ts_millis    |dt_frmt |
#+-------------+--------+
#|1683825723389|20230511|
#+-------------+--------+
```